# Python Pathlib - path with spaces issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a filesystem path setup like this where a directory name with spaces is symlinked to a directory with no spaces (to try and circumvent issues such as this):

```
$ ls -lR
drwxr-xr-x  3 user  group    96 Nov 25 15:37 with - spaces/
lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  group    18 Nov 25 15:28 with_no_spaces@ -> /tmp/with - spaces
./with - spaces:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  5 user  group  160 Nov 25 15:37 dir1/

./with - spaces/dir1:
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 user  group  0 Nov 25 15:37 a
-rw-r--r--  1 user  group  0 Nov 25 15:37 b
-rw-r--r--  1 user  group  0 Nov 25 15:37 c
```

I would like to use the `pathlib` module to iterate over the `a, b, c` files in `dir1` and get the absolute path of each.

```
$ pwd
/private/tmp/with - spaces/dir1

import pathlib
p = pathlib.Path(".")
file_names = [_file.absolute().as_posix() for _file in p.iterdir()]
print(file_names)
#['/private/tmp/with - spaces/dir1/a',
# '/private/tmp/with - spaces/dir1/c',
# '/private/tmp/with - spaces/dir1/b']
```

This works as expected but these file paths are then consumed by a downstream system (spark) and causes issues because of the paths with spaces.  Is there a platform-agnostic way to handle this with `pathlib` or maybe escape characters, or something else?

Using python 3.7.4

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I can't really pin it down since your code is working as it should, and you didn't detail how the down stream works. However, in most platforms, path arguments with spaces in them are usually fine as long as they are in double quotes.

So try this (assuming python 3.6+):

```
file_names = [f'"{_file.absolute().as_posix()}"' for _file in p.iterdir()]
```

Or this for all python versions:

```
file_names = ['"' + _file.absolute().as_posix() + '"' for _file in p.iterdir()]
```

Answer (score -1):

you should replace your spaces `.replace(" ", "\\ ");`

Comment: I tried this: `[_file.as_posix().replace(' ', '\\ ') for _file in pathlib.Path(LIB_DIR).iterdir()]`.  This produces `['/private/tmp/with\\ -\\ spaces/dir1/a','/private/tmp/with\\ -\\ spaces/dir1/c',  '/private/tmp/with\\ -\\ spaces/dir1/b']`.  The extra forward slash is resulting in "no such file or directory" error messages.

Comment: i also tried with a single forward slash in the `replace` and the output still had 2 forward slashes

Comment: what is your spark version?